# Conformal mapping for constant Gauss Curvature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conformal-geometry

The Sine-Gordon equation describes varying angles, conserving differential lengths in a mapping with constant Gauss curvature by means of an ODE.

In which conformal mapping (conserving angles), can we vary lengths with constant Gauss curvature?

EDIT1/2:

(It frustrated me much to find no answer in standard DG texts that I could access. Loxodromes on spheres and pseudospheres I consider to be too trivial.)

EDIT 3 :

A bit of research I have so far done:

If $k_1,k_2,k_n,\tau_g$ are respectively principal & normal curvatures, geodesic torsion and  $ k_{hs}, k_{hd} $ are half sum (average) and half difference principal curvatures, then

$$ (k_n - k_{hs})^2 + \tau_g ^2 = k_{hd}^2. $$

Attempts to visualize these curves on spheres/ pseudospheres will be highly appreciated I am sure, by the community as well.